# Hide external element on page load

Tags: javascript

I am using the Incapsuala Web Application Firewall. It allows me to display the Incapsula seal on the bottom left of my pages. However, I have a few pop up pages that I need to generate for some PDF report - the pop up pages are showing the seal and as a result are also displaying on the generated PDF documents.

I think the following is the Incapsula code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {
var _analytics_scr = document.createElement('script');
_analytics_scr.type = 'text/javascript'; _analytics_scr.async = true; _analytics_scr.src = '/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=9e14fec597ae623cd2f9cd71c4403630&ns=36';
var _analytics_elem = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; _analytics_elem.parentNode.insertBefore(_analytics_scr, _analytics_elem);
})();
// ]]>
</script>
```

How can I hide this when the pop up page is generated?

Comment: Wrap it in a function, and only call it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe this will help, but you can use `Phontom.js`
Use `page.onResourceRequested` method to abort all requests to google analytics.

You can read up on it [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/loadurlwithoutcss.js)

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    if ((/google-analytics\.com/gi).test(requestData['url'])){
        console.log('Request to GA. Aborting: ' + requestData['url']);
        request.abort();
    }
};
```